# Trouble adding -OriginalFileName tag using exiftool

Tags: python, exiftool

When i type in the following command

```
exiftool -config .ExifTool_config -o "/volumes/xsan2/lvis/level1/mjd/58680/camera2/images/LVISCAM2_ABoVE2019_0716_R2002_083194.JPG" -GPSDateStamp="2019-07-16" -GPSTimeStamp="23:06:34" -GPSLatitude="62.090340" -GPSLongitude="114.193019" -GPSLatitudeRef="N" -GPSLongitudeRef="W" -GPSAltitude="2822.12" -GPSRoll="-2.76" -GPSPitch="-0.19" -GPSImgDirection="96.38" -GPSImgDirectionRef="T" -Creator="Nasa's Classic (lvis.gsfc.nasa.gov)" -UserComment="Instrument: NASA's Classic (lvis.gsfc.nasa.gov), Mission: ABoVE2019, Platform: GLF5_N95NA" -OriginalFileName="/volumes/xsan2/lvis/archive/mjd/58680/GLF5_N95NA/camera/classic/LVISCAM1_2019_07_16_051912.JPG"
```

I get this error:

Error: Can't create JPEG files from scratch
    1 files weren't created due to errors

However if i take out the tagname -OriginalFileName but still leave the filename in quotes like so

```
exiftool -config .ExifTool_config -o "/volumes/xsan2/lvis/level1/mjd/58680/camera2/images/LVISCAM2_ABoVE2019_0716_R2002_083194.JPG" -GPSDateStamp="2019-07-16" -GPSTimeStamp="23:06:34" -GPSLatitude="62.090340" -GPSLongitude="114.193019" -GPSLatitudeRef="N" -GPSLongitudeRef="W" -GPSAltitude="2822.12" -GPSRoll="-2.76" -GPSPitch="-0.19" -GPSImgDirection="96.38" -GPSImgDirectionRef="T" -Creator="Nasa's Classic (lvis.gsfc.nasa.gov)" -UserComment="Instrument: NASA's Classic (lvis.gsfc.nasa.gov), Mission: ABoVE2019, Platform: GLF5_N95NA" "/volumes/xsan2/lvis/archive/mjd/58680/GLF5_N95NA/camera/classic/LVISCAM1_2019_07_16_051912.JPG"
```

It updates the file like I expected it too.

Why does it not like the -OriginalFileName tag name???

Answer (score 0):

The `OriginalFileName` tag assignment works fine.  The problem is that you are not actually processing any files.  Any time there is a `Can't create JPEG files from scratch` error, that means that ExifTool has not been given a file to actually process or the filename it has been given doesn't exist.

In the first command, you are assigning a value of
`"/volumes/xsan2/lvis/archive/mjd/58680/GLF5_N95NA/camera/classic/LVISCAM1_2019_07_16_051912.JPG"`
to the `OriginalFileName`.  But you have not included the actual file path so exiftool knows what file you want to process.  By removing the `-OriginalFileName=` from the second command, exiftool now has a file to actually process.

If you want to have `OriginalFileName` include the directory and file names, you can use either
`-OriginalFileName=%d%f`
to include the directory and filename based upon the source files. In this case, if the source is an absolute path, then the result will be the absolute path.  If it's a relative path, the the result will be the relative path.

Or you can use
`"-OriginalFileName<FilePath"`
`FilePath` will always be the absolute path of the file.

*Edit:*
To break down your command in response to your comment.  I'm sorry if I seem patronizing here, I don't mean to be, but because your command is longer than can be easily displayed here, it's hard to see all the details.
`exiftool`
This runs exiftool

`-config .ExifTool_config`
This tells exiftool to use the `.ExifTool_config` file.  As the `-config` option must be the first option in the command when it is used, this is the proper place for it.  If you place this file in the same directory as exiftool, then it will automatically be used without need of the `-config` option.

`-o "/volumes/xsan2/lvis/level1/mjd/58680/camera2/images/LVISCAM2_ABoVE2019_0716_R2002_083194.JPG"`
This option will create a new file with the file path of `/volumes/xsan2/lvis/level1/mjd/58680/camera2/images/LVISCAM2_ABoVE2019_0716_R2002_083194.JPG` with all new data being written to this file.  The original file will not be changed in any way.

`-GPSDateStamp="2019-07-16"`
Set the `GPSDateStamp` tag to a value of `2019:07:16`. Take note that while exiftool will write the date correctly in this case, that this format is not the proper way to format dates for exiftool to set.  You should use colons instead of dashes.  This could lead to a hard to find error.  See [Exiftool FAQ #5](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q5) for details.

`-GPSTimeStamp="23:06:34"`
Set the `GPSTimeStamp` tag to a value of `23:06:34`

`-GPSLatitude="62.090340"`
Set the `GPSLatitude` tag to a value of `62.090340`

`-GPSLongitude="114.193019"`
Set the `GPSLongitude` tag to a value of `114.193019`

`-GPSLatitudeRef="N"`
Set the `GPSLatitudeRef` tag to a value of `N`

`-GPSLongitudeRef="W"`
Set the `GPSLongitudeRef` tag to a value of `W`

`-GPSAltitude="2822.12"`
Set the `GPSAltitude` tag to a value of `2822.12`

`-GPSRoll="-2.76"`
Set the `GPSRoll` tag to a value of `-2.76`

`-GPSPitch="-0.19"`
Set the `GPSPitch` tag to a value of `-0.19`

`-GPSImgDirection="96.38"`
Set the `GPSImgDirection` tag to a value of `96.38`

`-GPSImgDirectionRef="T"` 
Set the `GPSImgDirectionRef` tag to a value of `T`

`-Creator="Nasa's Classic (lvis.gsfc.nasa.gov)"`
Set the `Creator` tag to a value of `Nasa's Classic (lvis.gsfc.nasa.gov`

`-UserComment="Instrument: NASA's Classic (lvis.gsfc.nasa.gov), Mission: ABoVE2019, Platform: GLF5_N95NA"`
Set the `UserComment` tag to a value of `Instrument: NASA's Classic…` (snipped data for brevity)

`-OriginalFileName="/volumes/xsan2/lvis/archive/mjd/58680/GLF5_N95NA/camera/classic/LVISCAM1_2019_07_16_051912.JPG"`
Set the `OriginalFileName` tag to a value of `/volumes/xsan2/lvis/archive/mjd/58680/GLF5_N95NA/camera/classic/LVISCAM1_2019_07_16_051912.JPG`

Now, take notice that the last line sets the value of the `OriginalFileName` tag only.  It does not tell exiftool to process that file.  You need to add the file name separately so exiftool knows what file it is going to process.

*Edit 2:*
Breakdown of your second comment.  When you add a space as you mention, your command becomes this:
`-OriginalFileName=`
This clears the value of the `OriginalFileName` tag.  If you check the newly created file, you will find that there is no `OriginalFileName` tag in it.

`"/volumes/xsan2/lvis/archive/mjd/58680/GLF5_N95NA/camera/classic/LVISCAM1_2019_07_16_051912.JPG"`
Now that this filepath is separated from everything else, it becomes visible to exiftool as a file to process.

Comment: I am very confused by your response.  How have i not included the directory?  /volumes/xsan2/lvis/archive/mjd/58680/GLF5_N95NA/camera/classic/ is the directory, and the file name is LVISCAM1_2019_07_16_051912.JPG

Comment: I found the error, i just needed a space between the equal sign and the file... OriginalFileName= "/volumes/xsan2/lvis/archive/mjd/58680/GLF5_N95NA/camera/classic/LVISCAM1_2019_07_16_045719.JPG"

Comment: Adding a space like that tells exiftool to clear the value of the `OriginalFileName`.  The addition of the space sets the file path apart so exiftool now sees it as a separate option.  If you check the file, you will see that the `OriginalFileName` has not been set.

Comment: Sorry i just reread your originally response, and i must have read it wrong the first several times... Ok i see now, so what you were saying was that the tag for OriginalFIleName was in fact correct, however i needed to also add the filepath and file name AFTER that so that the command would know which file.  I get it now.  Thank you!

Comment: Just so you know, if you have any other questions regarding Exiftool, you might try the [ExifTool Forums](https://exiftool.org/forum).  The author is quite active there.